# IOS/Objective-C: Retrieve NSArray from completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, completion-block

I am trying to retrieve an array of `EKReminders` from a completion block of a method.  The method returns the array I desire.  However, I can't find a good way to obtain it back on the main thread at known time such that that I know the block has completed.

To retrieve `EKReminders`, Apple requires a completion block approach (in contrast to `EKEvents`.)  So my fetch code contains the following:

```
-(void) fetchReminders{
[self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
        self.reminders = reminders;
 }];
}
```

The above code successfully runs and places reminders in the ivar once finished..

The problem is I don't know when the block completes so if I merely try to access self.reminders in viewwillappear after callng the above method, it returns empty presumably because the block has not yet completed  I would like some way to set the ivar when I know that the block has completed to eliminate the race condition.

A number of answers on SO for how to retrieve a value form a completion block recommend passing in a completion block to the method as follows:

```
//change above method to 
-(void) fetchReminders withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *reminders))completion; {

and call it in viewwillappear with:
  [self fetchReminders withCompletion:^(NSArray* reminders) {
        self.reminders =remindersArray;
        NSLog(@"remindersArray in viewwillappear%@",remindersArray);
    }];
```

When I try this, the completion block in `viewwillappear` never fires so something is going wrong.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to successfully retrieve at a known point in time an array retrieved within a completion block.

Comment: Why don't you call the method you wanna execute after setting like `self.reminders =remindersArray; [self someMethodUsingReminders];` If you want it to be on main thread then wrap the call in dispatch_async and pass main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various different ways to achieve that.
You can either set up a key value observer or a NSNotification or do your necessary actions in your setter method of your `reminders` object or even just call your necessary actions in that completionHandler block.

**Calling out from the handler block**

```
-(void) fetchReminders{
   [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate 
    completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.reminders = reminders;
            [self doWhatYaGottaDoMethod];
        });
    }];
 }
```

**Key Value Observer Method**
When your view loads you can add a key value observer like this:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"self.reminders"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
          context:nil];
```

And implement this method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context{

     if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"self.reminders"]){
         //You got your reminders, do what you gotta do
      }
}
```

Make sure to remove observers when your viewController is dealloacted or you may get a crash